# How to execute multiple lines of (cmd) shell from R in the same shell session?

Tags: r

I have a problem in that I cannot seem to evaluate multiple lines of cmd from R in the same cmd session.

#### Minimal example

Opening cmd on windows, and running

```
set a=3
ECHO %a%
```

returns the value of `a` (3) as expected.

I cannot get this result running the same code from R using `shell()` or any other R function e.g. `system()`

#### What I've tried so far

I've tried 4 obvious attempts

```r
shell("set a=3")
shell("ECHO %a%")
# %a%


shell("set a=3 & ECHO %a%")
# %a%


shell("set a=3 && ECHO %a%")
# %a%


shell("set a=3
      ECHO %a%", intern=TRUE)
# character(0)
```

The desired result is to be able to execute the cmd code `"set a=3 && ECHO %a%"` from R and have it return `3` instead of `%a%`

#### Question

How can I run multiple lines of cmd code from R and have them all evaluate within the same cmd session?

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not absolutely sure as to the "why" this won't work like it does in the terminal. I am assuming it has something to do with the active environment and access to system. This is an ugly workaround, but essentially what I know will work is setting the environment variable via `Sys.setenv` and then accessing it via `shell`. So here's a wrapper... i don't know if this helps your situation or not:

```
.shellset <- function(...) {
    var_cmd <- list(...)
    Sys.setenv(...)
    cmd_vars <- paste(sprintf("%%%s%%", names(var_cmd)), collapse = " ")
    shell(sprintf("echo %s", cmd_vars))
}
```

Essentially we set the environ variables internally to the function and cat the output via shell... but i genuinely don't know what this would accomplish.

Here's terminal interactions and running. Best of luck

[image]